# Question about usage of 「のでは」

Tags: grammar, usage, jlpt, ellipsis

In one of the grammar questions for N3, I saw one for which I couldn't understand the reason why のでは is used.

> この英会話講師のアルバイトに応募したきっかけは、先輩からの紹介です。私の専門は言語学ですので、その知識が生かせる「　」、と思い、応募いたしました。文法に詳しいので、英語はもちろん、日本語での文法の説明もできます。

Possible answers are

> 1) から　２）とか　３）なんて　４）のでは

The answer marked as correct is のでは. However, I don't understand why. I know that のでは　is used in sentences like のではない。However, that's not he case here.　Also as ので、when implying reason. However in that case I don't see は added. When searching through google I found more cases where you can use like this "一歩間違えば指先に刺さるのではと思ってしまう".

However, I don't understand which grammar rule allows for this usage of のでは。

Comment: `In one of the grammar questions...`  Is this a JLPT question?  If so, you can add the `jlpt` tag to the topic that would make it more helpful.

Comment: I added jlpt tag. There is no tag for n3 currently, I can't make one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are close. The omitted phrase is その知識が生かせるのではない**か**, where か is the question marking particle you must know well.

It says "Can't I make use of the knowledge? (I can!)"  rather than saying "I can't make use of the knowledge".

Similarly, 刺さるのでは in that context means 刺さるのでは**ない（だろう）か**, meaning "I wonder if it pricks".

Answer (score 2):

The "のでは" here implies it's one's (humble) opinion or suspicion.

One can also say "その知識が生かせるかと思い".

I presume this usage is related to "のではない".

Answer (score 2):

**のでは describes possibility.**

> 私の専門は言語学ですので、その知識が生かせる「　」、と思い、応募いたしました。

I applied this opportunity because my proficient is Linguistics.
It's possible to take advantage of my knowledge.

Japan's Cultural expression way, we do not insist directly.
If this is English,
I am sure that I can take advantage of my skills in this field.
In Japan, we softly insist , that's why のでは is added.
のでは have effect to make the things more softly.

> 私の専門は言語学ですので、その知識が生かせると思い、応募いたしました。

In gramatical,
This sentence is also collect ,perfectly works.
You can use when you want to approach strongly.